# How to raise event when Current application property is changed

Tags: wpf, mvvm, object

I have a WPF application.

In my App.xaml.cs I save the full name of the logged in user as follows:

App.Current.Properties["FullName"] = GetValueFromDatabase();

I have two screens/windows in the same application.

First is the users scrren, which has a an editable WPF data grid where I can update full name of the current  user. 
  Second is a screen which has a Label/TextBox control which displays the Current users fullname from the Application object.

When both the windows are open, if I change the full name of the user and save the changes in the first screen. I want to trigger an event so that, it is also reflected in the second screen immediately?

Which event do I hook to this application and how?

I am using MVVM pattern and entity framework.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [dependency property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx) or make sure your model is an [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) so that others can bind to it in either the screen or window using a {Binding}

```
// if your model is derived from a sub-class of DependencyObject....
class Model : DependencyObject 
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyStringProperty = 
            DependencyProperty.Register("MyString", typeof(string), 
            typeof(IncidentGraphic), new UIPropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

    public string MyString
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MyStringProperty ); }
        set { SetValue(MyStringProperty , value); }
    }
}

/// recommended to use INotifyPropertyChanged
class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     private void NotifyChange(string property)
     {
         PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
         if (handler != null)
         {
             handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
         }
     }

     string m_MyString = string.Empty;
     public string MyString
     {
         get
         {
             return m_MyString ;
         }
         set
         {
             if ( value != this.m_MyString )
             {
                 this. m_MyString  = value;
                 NotifyChange("MyString");
             }
             }
     }
}

// in your xaml.....
    <TextBox Text="{Binding MyString}" />
```

Comment: Thank you Chris. But considering given scenario, If I raise the event in the 1st screen, would it be immediately updated in the second? Would have to try it out.

Comment: yes, it will pretty much update immediately.  the wpf framework sends a "property changed" event and whatever is bound to the property will update itself without any intervention from you.  no extra code needed.